# How on earth did I get this feature in Firefox

Tags: firefox, screen-resolution

I accidentally pressed something in Firefox and this feature suddenly appears. Now I can view a webpage in different screen resolutions...

What is it and how did I get it? (I want to use it again haha)

http://screencast.com/t/tHblDMJydQ

Tnx

Comment: I've been staring the screen for five minutes but I still don't see the programming-related part of the question...

Comment: Well, it's an easy way to view your website in different resolutions. Like if youre making something for mobile. Of if you want to see it in a big resolution without having a big monitor...

Comment: Dan, I know, but when I wanted to accept the answer, I got a box that said to me I have to wait 15 more minutes... And after that I got afk :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

responsive design view Ctrl + Shift + M